# Как оформить предложение?

Tags: пунктуация

Выношу на обсуждение следующий вопрос. Есть предложение в котором стоят подряд два тире. Вопрос: можно ли оставить так? И если нет, то как заменить? Подходят ли мои варианты или есть какой-то другой - лучший?

Предлагаются к обсуждению разноэффективные проекты — предложения, решающие разными средствами одну и ту же задачу — поставки природного газа в Европу, эффективность которых неодинакова.

1) Предлагаются к обсуждению разноэффективные проекты — предложения, решающие разными средствами одну и ту же задачу (поставки природного газа в Европу), эффективность которых неодинакова.

2) Предлагаются к обсуждению разноэффективные проекты (предложения, решающие разными средствами одну и ту же задачу — поставки природного газа в Европу), эффективность которых неодинакова.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше применить вариант со скобками (или даже без них при отсутствии в тексте уточняющего значения):

(1)Предлагаются к обсуждению разноэффективные проекты — предложения, решающие разными средствами одну и ту же задачу (поставки природного газа в Европу), эффективность которых неодинакова.

(2)Предлагаются к обсуждению разноэффективные проекты — предложения, решающие разными средствами одну и ту же задачу поставки природного газа в Европу, эффективность которых неодинакова.